# Error when setting up Parse in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hi iv'e just started a new app and am now following the parse quick start guide to setup parse in this project. Everything works fine until I put this code into my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

Then when I try to run my app I get this message in the gradle console:

*AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
 FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 4.588 secs*

Here is my current build.grade code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.src.parseapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
//Parse Dependencies
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

}

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error I compiled and ran my program with the 2 files bolts-tasks-1.3.0.jar and Parse-1.11.0.jar in the libs folder.

Then I added all the rest of the Parse stuff except for the dependencies lines. 
The problem is that android studio was trying to add the parse .jar files twice.

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) already compiles stuff in the libs folder